# How to delete the lines from certain lines to another certain lines with python

Tags: python

I have a file displayed as follows. I want to delete the lines start from `>rev_` until the next line with `>`, not delete the `>` line. I want a python code to realize it.
input file:

```
>name1
fgrsagrhshsjtdkj
jfsdljgagdahdrah
gsag
>rev_name1                # delete from here
jfdsfjdlsgrgagrehdsah
fsagasfd                  # until here
>name2
jfosajgreajljioesfg
fjsdsagjljljlj
>rev_name2                # delete from here
jflsajgljkop
ljljasffdsa               # until here
>name3
.......
```

output file:

```
>name1
fgrsagrhshsjtdkj
jfsdljgagdahdrah
gsag
>name2
jfosajgreajljioesfg
fjsdsagjljljlj
>name3
.......
```

My code is as follows, but it can not work.

```
mark = {}
with open("human.fasta") as inf, open("human_norev.fasta",'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        if line[0:5] == '>rev_':
            mark[line] = 1
        elif line[0] == '>':
            mark[line] = 0
    if mark[line] == 0:
        outf.write(line)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you want a program, write one. If you can't, learn how to program or hire a programmer. We aren't your lackeys. I want world peace but simply wanting it doesn't seem to get it done.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that you "want a code", but what is your question? Which part of the solution are you having trouble with? Please show what you've written so far.

Comment: Did you try [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=fasta+remove+sequences+python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because (among other things) you're not marking lines that neither start with `>rev` nor with `>`. Also, you'd need another loop for outputting all the lines that have been marked for output - right now you're only outputting the last one.

Alec's answer is nice, but I'll suggest a different approach using a regular expression:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r">rev_[^>]*")
with open("human.fasta") as inf, open("human_norev.fasta", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(regex.sub("", inf.read()))
```

Test the regex [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hA2ZTT/1).

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend at least trying to come up with a solution on your own before asking us on here. Ask yourself questions regarding what different ways I can work towards a solution, will parsing character by character/line by line/regex be sufficient for this problem.

But in this case since determining when to start and stop removing lines was always at the start of the line it made sense to just go line by line and check the starting few characters.

```
i = """>name1
fgrsagrhshsjtdkj
jfsdljgagdahdrah
gsag
>rev_name1                # delete from here
jfdsfjdlsgrgagrehdsah
fsagasfd                  # until here
>name2
jfosajgreajljioesfg
fjsdsagjljljlj
>rev_name2                # delete from here"""

final_string = ""
keep_line = True

for line in i.split('\n'):

    if line[0:5] == ">rev_":
        keep_line = False
    elif line[0] == '>':
        keep_line = True

    if keep_line:
        final_string += line + '\n'

print(final_string)
```

If you wanted the lines to just go directly to console you could remove the print at the end and replace `final_string += line + '\n'` with a `print(line)`.

Comment: Look at my rep, but fine.

Comment: Taking care of your rep right now :)

Comment: Thanks, thought it might be better to post an answer just recommending they try it on their own than nothing at all. So I added a solution as to not get down voted to oblivion.

Answer (score 1):

The code also can be as follows:

```
with open("human.fasta") as inf, open("human_norev.fasta",'w') as outf:
    del_start = False
    for line in inf:
        if line.startswith('>rev_'):
            del_start = True
        elif line.startswith('>'):
            del_start = False

        if not del_start:
            outf.write(line)
```

Comment: The `and del_start` part of your `elif` is not really necessary. Also, the code snippet feature is only usable with JavaScript - other code simply needs to be indented by four spaces (select, press Ctrl-K). You can upvote helpful answers by clicking on the upwards-pointing triangle next to the vote counter for each answer, and you can accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking the checkmark next to it. That's the appropriate way of saying Thanks on StackOverflow. Of course, you can accept your own answer if it's the one you like best. Have fun!